# EE 2 Multi site with one theme

Tags: ee2, multi-site-manager, themes, multiple-sites

I have a network of 3 sites that have the exact same channels and design - just different entries. Is there a way to use the same theme for all three sites rather than having to duplicate the theme and maintain 3 different sets of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. One way would be to turn on `Save Templates as Files` as in your `Global Template Preferences`, so your templates get saved to `/system/expressionengine/templates/` and you can share between sites. You'll also need to update the `Server path to site's templates` accordingly.

Or, even more simple, you could maintain one set of "master" templates and in your secondary sites simply use `{embed=site_a:group/template}` as appropriate.

That said, if you have "different entries", won't the content of templates be different as well, if only because you need to specify a different channel= parameter? The second method has the advantage of allowing you to only replicate certain templates and not others, of course, maintaining full control over your setup.